# What makes air to spin?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, atmospheric-science, air, vortex, coriolis-effect

The phenomenon is observed in tornadoes where the air spins with a great speed causing so much damage. Can there be any experiment that can be performed to make the air spin in clockwise or counterclockwise direction?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all tornadoes rotate in the direction of cyclones: anti-clockwise on the Northern hemisphere. But a few percent are the other way around (clockwise on the Northern hemisphere). Because sometimes the rotational moment of vortex of the air where it forms (at a much smaller scale than an ordinary low-pressure system) happens to be the other way around.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticyclonic_tornado

Comment: this answer does not give a reasoning.

Comment: @AHB  I supposed people here would know about conservation of angular momentum. Difficult to make the air spin - it already does. On a large scale always in the direction of the Earth's rotation.

Comment: In your answer, you just said some tornadoes are clockwise and some happen to be anti-clockwise. The OP probably knew this fact.